# Is there a more efficient way to write a dataframe (columns and data) to list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I haven't found a function to write a dataframe with columns and data to a list. I feel like there must be a function for this, but I can't find it so instead I concatenate together.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['Project1', 'CT', 800], ['Project2', 'MA', 1000], ['Project3', 'CA', 20]], columns=['Project ID', 'State', 'Cost'])

print [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
```

Desired output:

```
[['Project ID', 'State', 'Cost'], ['Project1', 'CT', 800L], ['Project2', 'MA', 1000L], ['Project3', 'CA', 20L]]
```

Comment: Your desired output seems a little strange to me. Did you perhaps want `[[0, 'Project1', 'CT', 800], [1, 'Project2', 'MA', 1000], [2, 'Project3', 'CA', 20]]`? If so, then `df.reset_index().values.tolist()` does the trick.

Comment: @JME I meant columns, not indexes as I want to write this to a csv file with the headers in place. I updated my original question.

Comment: if you ultimately are writing to csv, can you just do df.to_csv() ?http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @measureallthethings really helpful. Exactly what I want, glad I mentioned I was ultimately going to a CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `transpose` operator to do the trick?

```
df.T.reset_index().values.T.tolist()

[['Project ID', 'State', 'Cost'],
 ['Project1', 'CT', 800],
 ['Project2', 'MA', 1000],
 ['Project3', 'CA', 20]]
```